# Alert innerHTML of a lot span

Tags: jquery, html

I have a lot span  like this

```
<span class="ttt" onclick="go($this());"  > home </span >
```

I want when clicked on every span  alert innerHTMLs

```
 Function go(rad) {
     Var neww =rad.innerHTML;
     alert (neww);
 }
```

Please help to me 
Thanks

Comment: Code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with your code:

- you pass `$(this())` where you intend to call `this` as a `function` and convert it into a jquery object. You need to pass the jquery object of `$(this)` instead
- you intend to pass a jquery object and then to use its `innerHTML`, while it has no such a thing. It has a `.html()` function instead
- I don't think `alert`ing html would be a good idea. I think you have meant `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`, so `.text()` instead of `.html()`
- `Function` is incorrect, you need `function` instead
- you did not format your code properly
- `var` instead of `Var`

This is how your html should look like

```
<span class="ttt" onclick="go($(this));"  > home </span >
```

and your Javascript

```
function go(rad) {
    var neww = rad.text();
    alert(neww);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span.ttt").on('click', function(){
    var val = $(this).html();
    alert(val);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ttt" > home </span >
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass (this) inside html tags it simply wont work.
and you can use jQuery to bind click event function to all spans with ttt class:

```
<span class="ttt">home</span>
```

and for the click function:

```
$('span.ttt').click(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

this should work with jQuery

Comment: *"you can't pass (this) inside html tags it simply wont work"* - Yes you can, it's just that the OP did it incorrectly and didn't define the function properly. `onclick="go(this);"` would work to call `go()` with the clicked element as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems with your existing code:

1. There is no `$this()` function. Your onclick handler should be:

   ```
   onclick="go(this);"
   ```
2. `Function` should be `function` - JS is case sensitive.
3. `Var` should be `var`.

Fix those issues and it works:

```js
function go(rad) {
  var neww = rad.innerHTML;
  alert (neww);
}
```

```html
<span class="ttt" onclick="go(this);"  > home </span>
<span class="ttt" onclick="go(this);"  > option b </span>
<span class="ttt" onclick="go(this);"  > option c </span>
```

However, given you've used the "jquery" tag on your question, you can tidy up the code by removing the inline `onclick` attributes from the HTML and just doing it all with some simple jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span.ttt").click(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ttt"> home </span>
<span class="ttt"> option b </span>
<span class="ttt"> option c </span>
```

Note that the `$(document).ready()` is optional if you include the JS in a script at the end of the document body (after the elements it references).

Comment: How can i add a text into web url without refresh i use ajax but dont work?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. (Sounds like that would be an unrelated question.)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without JQuery by attaching a click event listener to the body to every element with the desired class. This method will work for any number of class members.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Click on Class</title></head>
<body onload="listen();">

<span class="ttt">Home</span>
<span class="ttt">About</span>
<span class="ttt">Contact</span>

<script>
    function listen() {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', function (element) {
            if (element.target.className === 'ttt') {
                alert(element.target.innerHTML);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```